# Can't display content in infowindow, I'm using google maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

thanks in advance, I'm stuck at the moment trying to figure out why my code is not working properly, I have been trying to display content using infowindow for the last few hours, I can't find why the content is not displaying inside the box. At the moment I am able to display multiple markers in the map in different locations depending the coordinates, now I just need to display the infowindow with some relevant content inside when clicking on the marker. I can display the infowindow but it is blank, it is not showing the string. Here I paste my function. Thanks again.

```
    function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
        var marker, i;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var image = 'http://193.168.3.5/Location&Tracking/images/taxiv7_trans_small.png';

        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(pos);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                icon: image


            });


            function placeMarker(location) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: map
                });
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() +
                        '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng()
                });
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            }


            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content:"Hello World!"
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {


                    infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);

                }
            })(marker, i));



        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to my own problem: 
The text inside the infowindow was displayed but the text colour was white as the background, witch it maked invisible. I have changed the text color by applying html code to it and change it to blue. I also was repeating when giving content: value and infowindow.open twice which didn't make any sense over writing the previous one.
Here I paste the corrected code, it works for me now.
Thanks anyway.

```
    function initialize() {

        //Create an object variable containing set of properties, to pass to the map
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false
        };

        // Intializing map by calling constructor
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
        var marker, i;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

       //set image to the icon marker
       var image = 'http://193.168.3.5/Location&Tracking/images/taxiv7_trans_small.png';


        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(pos);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                icon: image


            });



            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {



           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content:'<p style="color:blue;"> This is marker No.'+markers[i][0]+'</p>'});


                    infowindow.open(map, marker);

                }
            })(marker, i));



        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```